# output array values based on constant - PHP

Tags: php, arrays, constants

Heres my code:

```
<?php
define("THEME", "grey");

$grey = array(5, 10, 15);
$blue = array(1, 3, 5);
?>
```

I would like to find a way to output a certain array based on what THEME is. So that something like

THEME[0] outputs 5, because THEME is set to grey and $grey[0] is 5.

I have looked up on some array functions, but I cannot find anything related to what I want to achieve.

Does anyone know how to achieve something like this?

Thank you.

Comment: Does anyone know a reason to achieve something like this?

Comment: @Col While maybe not the optimal solution to whatever problem he's trying to solve, it's a valid question. Serial down voting not appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're basically looking for the [variable variable syntax](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.variables.variable.php):

```
define("THEME", "grey");

$grey = array(5, 10, 15);
$blue = array(1, 3, 5);

echo ${THEME}[0];
```

Answer (score 1):

```
echo ${THEME}[0];
```

Comment: exactly what i was looking for. hmm why'd this get voted down :/

Answer (score 0):

You're basically looking for the some sort of quite unusual way of using **arrays**.
There is no reason to use constants nor global variables. Plain variable for the theme and array will suit you perfectly.

```
<?php 
$themes = array(
  'grey' => array(5, 10, 15),
  'blue' => array(1, 3, 5),
}
$THEME = 'grey'; 

echo $themes[$THEME][1];
?>
```